# Using JavaScript to show next button when slider has been moved

Tags: javascript

In my Qualtrics survey I am trying to get the next button to appear either after participants had made a response on a slider or autoadvance after 5 seconds. I've only been trying to figure out how to do this by using the mousedown command as I'm not sure how I'd code dragging a slider. This is what I have so far; itss advancing after 5 seconds but the next button isn't appearing. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
var mouseDown = 0;

document.body.onmousedown = function() { 

 ++mouseDown;

}

document.body.onmouseup = function() {

 --mouseDown;

}



Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() 

{

this.hideNextButton();

if (mouseDown) {

this.showNextButton();

} else {

this.clickNextButton.delay(5);

} 

});



Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()

{

/*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/



});



Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()

{

/*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/



});
```

Comment: Idea: the slider component might have an event like `slidechange` or something, depends on the slider.